# SageMaker pipeline execution after commit is not triggered

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create a simple pipeline in SageMaker Studio with the tutorial presented here: https://sagemaker-immersionday.workshop.aws/lab6.html

I have followed every step and everything seemed fine, but when I pushed the code to the repository, a new pipeline execution was not created.

There are no errors in the SageMaker Studio and the Amazon EventBridge rules (that are used to trigger the pipeline execution) are defined.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to execute the notebook with Option 1, then let's assume the problem is in Option 2 at the code commit step (your troubleshooting ruled out other likely steps).
There is an extra step in the Sagemaker Studio git commit process from the UI - you have to select which files are tracked, and then commit them.  In addition to checking logs, you could check the code commit repo and confirm that the updated code is in the repository.
The new files that you commit are what triggers the EventBridge job.